# codeigniter - manipulate a CI_DB_mysql_result Object

Tags: php, codeigniter

a print_r of my `$query->results()` array gives me for example:

```
CI_DB_mysql_result Object
        (
            [conn_id] => Resource id #28
            [result_id] => Resource id #45
            [result_array] => Array
                (
                )

            [result_object] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                       (
                            [id] => 3
                            [is_tool] => 1
                       )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                       (
                            [id] => 7
                            [is_tool] => 0
                       )
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                       (
                            [id] => 12
                            [is_tool] => 1
                       )
                    [3] => stdClass Object
                       (
                            [id] => 13
                            [is_tool] => 0
                       )
                 )

             [custom_result_object] => Array
            (
            )

        [current_row] => 0
        [num_rows] => 10
        [row_data] => 
    )
```

I would like to manipulate the result above by removing one or more stdClass Objects and updating the [num_rows] to the number of rows I'm left with but otherwise leave the array as if it was the result of a db query as my original `$query` variable.

Is this possible and how could I go about doing that?

Many thanks.

Comment: why? Why not just dump the result normally and then manipulate the data.

Comment: because I have old code after this that is expecting a CI_DB_mysql_result type and I would like to avoid changing that older code.

Comment: Change the older code then. You can never "know" what the output is going to be as its not intended to be manipulated at that point without a lot of work, and by the time you write the code to somehow do that, you could of rewritten that older code to simply take the results.

Comment: ok, you're right. Changing that old code is really the way to do this. Maybe this was a faster way to solve the problem but I can see that's it's neither faster nor elegant. Thanks.

Comment: +1. I agree, it's always better to change your code rather than the third party code.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your result set, making sure you pass by reference in your `foreach` using an ampersand:

```
foreach($records->result() AS &$record) {
   unset($record->x); // Remove a key
   $record->foo = 'Bar'; // Add a key
}
```

**BEWARE:- This doesn't work in all versions of PHP 5!**

You also could try extending the `CI_DB_mysql_result` class and returning an instance of that instead so long as it remains compatible with the default implementation. Then you could augment the `num_rows` method to include your custom code.